# Not getting Date in SQL server in the format 23rd December 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the date in the format for example 23rd December 2014 in SQL server 2008.
I am using

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)`

but it is not adding any suffix to the date part.
I found out a function in MySQL but in SQL server its difficult.

Comment: What *are* you getting?

Comment: This is a formatting issue and should therefore be performed by your presentation layer e.g. report, webpage, form, etc.

Comment: @gvee -- maybe it's just a simple query and doesn't have a presentation layer.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using the date as is? Dates should only be formatted for display to clients or exporting to text files, which should be done client-side or by the reporting engine. In all other cases you should use strongly-typed values to avoid conversion errors

Comment: @roryap then a missing suffix wouldn't matter `;-)`

Comment: I am getting date in the format 23 Dec 2014.

Comment: So by "it is not adding any suffix to the date part" you expected we'd understand that you meant it was returning "Dec" instead of "December"?  You need to give us a little more to work with if you want to get help...

Comment: Write a function that parses the date and constructs the string you want.

Comment: Yes , Actually we need to get this output from Stored Procedure and display it in a report with the required format.

Comment: I would suggest you say "But it's returning `23 Dec 2014` instead of `23rd December 2014`".

Comment: Yes it is returning 23 Dec 2014 instead of 23rd December 2014.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: Leave the formatting to the front end. SQL server is not the right place for formatting.

Comment: @SeanLange Sure I will try to handle the conversion in the front end. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with all versions of SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateString
(
    @Date datetime
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Day    varchar(10) = DATENAME(DAY, @Date)
    DECLARE @Month  varchar(20) = DATENAME(MONTH, @Date)
    DECLARE @Year   varchar(4)  = DATENAME(YEAR, @Date)

    SET @Day = @Day + CASE
                        WHEN RIGHT(@Day,1) = '1' THEN 'st'
                        WHEN RIGHT(@Day,1) = '2' THEN 'nd'
                        WHEN RIGHT(@Day,1) = '3' THEN 'rd'
                        ELSE 'th'
                      END
    RETURN @Day + ' ' + @Month + ' ' + @Year
END
```

Comment: Ouch. Scalar functions are horrible for performance. This is one more reason to leave the formatting to the front end.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree with you, but when the OP insisted that formatting must be done in SQL Server, there wasn't much choice :(

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function to format a string in the same way you would with .NET, eg:

```
declare @d datetime=GETDATE()
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-gb' )
```

or

```
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'dd MMMM yyyy')
```

Previous versions do not have good formatting support and the only other option is to extract the names of the various date parts to construct the final string using [DATENAME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), eg:

```
select datename(day,@d) + ' ' +  datename(month,@d) +  ' ' + datename(year,@d)
```

That said, it's better to return strongly typed date values to clients or reporting engines and let the conversion happen at the client's side, not in SQL. This avoids conversion errors and performance issues

Comment: Is there anything that can be done in SQL server 2008?

Comment: You should specify the database version in the question itself. Anyway, I just added a solution using DATENAME